# Article vs plural

Tags: grammar, articles

Do these sentences mean the same thing?, Or is "oranges" more specific than An orange.

> 1 An orange has lots of vitamin C.

> 2 Oranges have lots of vitamin C.

Comment: Both are the same.

Comment: @Anonymous don't do that.  Don't put a half answer in a comment. Either answer properly or don't answer at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually the reverse: *an orange* is more specific than *oranges*.

---

*An orange* specifies a single orange. It could even be paraphrased using that word:

- A single orange has lots of vitamin C.
- One orange has lots of vitamin C.

*Oranges* describes oranges in a *general* sense, not a specific sense. Although the meaning of *an orange* could be inferred, certain sentences would make no sense with such an inference:

- ✔ People built the pyramids.
- ✘ A person built the pyramids.

In that construction, it's only possible for many people, working together, to have done something.

---

*A thing* is more specific than *things*. Rather than referring to a vague grouping of things, where an actual number is not specified, *a thing* gives an explicit number: one.

---

Note that a more specific meaning you could provide would be something like this:

- One of *these* oranges has lots of vitamin C.
- An orange *from this group* has lots of vitamin C.

In those sentences, you're not just talking about any single orange, but a single orange from a specifically identified set.

---

And the *most* specific meaning you could provide would be this:

- *This* orange has lots of vitamin C.

It's no longer any single orange from a particular set, but one specific orange as opposed to any others at all.